# Linux/Bash: Create relative soft links to files in directory tree?

Tags: linux, bash, hyperlink

I'd like to make links to all files in a directory tree.
Which means, create the same directory structure and make the links in them to the respective subdirectory in the original dir.

That could be done with

```
cp -R -s ../foo .
```

But - that needs an absolute path. So rather

```
cp -R -s `readlink -e ../foo` `readlink -e .`
```

I would like the resulting links to be relative.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can put some more glob pattern in front of `../foo` like this:

```
cp -R -s ../foo/* .
```

This will create relative symbolic links in current directory of all files/directories found in `../foo/*` path.

Answer (score 0):

Linux cp only makes symbolic links for the current directory, that means it will not link any files under subdirectories in the source path.

A script should be the answer, but [this article may be helpful too](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136360/generate-multiple-symbolic-links-with-maitaining-directory-structure).